# Как доказать полноту системы булевых функций без использования Теоремы Поста?

Tags: алгоритм, дискретная-математика

Стоит задача доказать полноту системы булевых функций без использования Теоремы Поста, но в интернете я пока к большому сожалению ничего найти не смог. Есть ли альтернативный способ доказательства?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите как строится [доказательство](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9._%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9#.D0.94.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C.) теоремы Поста. Если вкратце, то из доступных функций строятся функции базиса ∧ , ∨, ¬, с помощью которых можно выразить любую функцию в дизъюнктивной нормальной форме.

Вам нужно сделать то же (т.е. построить функции отрицания, конъюнкцию и дизъюнкцию), только использовать не абстрактные функции из классов фигурирующих в теореме Поста, а доступные вам функции из системы.